# buying pistol magazine upgrades

Tags: mass-effect-3

Where can I buy these? I am pretty sure (i.e. I checked) the following locations:

- Nos Astra Sporting goods
- Batarian State Arms
- Sitra Suplies
- Kassa Fabrication
- Aegohr Munitions
- Spectre Requisitions
- Cipritine Armory
- Elkoss Combine Arsenal Supplies

Kinda frustrating that a Paladin X only has like 40 shots with level II magazine upgrade.

Comment: You're missing at least one store (Kanala Exports to be specific).  Have you tried looking there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weapon mods become available for purchase as you complete missions. Some or all of them may be actually available to pick up for free in the mission they appear after, in which case you won't have to buy them.

It is entirely possible to have all weapon mods at level 5 by the end of the first playthrough. Some or all of them may be downgraded a level, presumably to populate the citadel stores.

Comment: But I assumed that if I had the level 1 version, I can buy the other levels. That is what I want to do.

Comment: @soandos that is not how the game works, unfortunately. The only way to unlock higher levels is to keep playing.

Comment: Almost done with my second play through, and I have only unlocked level 2?

Comment: Have you completed All The Sidequests? I do not know if missing a sidequest will unlock the items that could be found during it. I have unlocked all of the mods by the end of my first playthrough. They were downgraded 1 level for playthrough 2, though, probably to populate the stores.